# How to Build a Swing GUI Builder kind of Application

Tags: swing

I want to develop an application like Swing GUI Builder where drag and drop of contents over the workspace will be possible.
How to achieve this? Is there any reference available.

Comment: Do you really think the world needs yet another (bloody) D'n'D Java GUI maker?  They are generally considered to only be good for newbies and prototyping.

Comment: I don't really think so. The NetBeans integrated visual GUI builder is extremely helpful for new and experienced java programmers.

Comment: I just want to develop a prototype of that. I actually want to develop drag and drop GUI for the Web components results to a development of web page. So wanted to know the core of it.

Comment: So you're trying to make a drag and drop for Web Components. In that case, you're not going to be messing with Layout Managers, but rather with CSS and html. This is significantly harder to do right. You can still look up the way to display components from the Matisse Project, but you're going to need to look at the source of Kompozer or some other WYSIWYG editor to know how to create the HTML code. I can't think of a good WYSIWG editor written in java, so you'll have to look through source code in another language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a huge task. Project Matisse did a lot of work on this which is now incorporated into the Netbeans IDE. This [link](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Interviews/violet_pavek_qa.html) is an interview with the person behind the matisse project, and talks about some of the challenges and how the team overcame them. You can use the layout manager they created, and looking through the Netbeans source code would probably give you some idea of how to go about building what you want.

Answer (score -2):

Download NetBeans from [NetBeans.org](http://www.netbeans.org), make sure you have the JDK (Java Development Kit), and use the GUI Builder in NetBeans. It's drag and drop and is easy to use. Documentation can be found at the homepage, and you should take a quick look at this [tutorial.](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-functionality.html#Exercise_3)